# Images in GridView disappear when turning phone side ways

Tags: android, image, gridview

I'm adding images to a gridview, everything works perfectly until I turn the phone sideways, all the images in the GridView disapper and this error appears on the log

```
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

The images I'm using for my GridView are taken with the phone camera like this

```
Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

After that I call the image Adapter

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
    case 0:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
           Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 100, 100, true);
           Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail);
           list.add(drawable);

           GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridV1);
           gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, list));

         }
    }
}
```

And finally this is where I add my images in the ImageAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageDrawable(mThumbIds.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
```

I think it has something to do with the scale, but I'm not sure, can't find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sochimickox said, your layout gets redrawn when you turn it. So there is two way that i see, first is disabling the redrawn. Since we know your error's cause is "spans", one of these should help you:

- [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499998/prevent-app-from-restarting-during-orientation-change)
- [Or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Probably the first would do it, but i recommend designing the app for both landscape and portait modes. To do that, you should crete one more folder in your resource named layout-port. Than you can simply copy the xml file here, select the portait look from top bar at "Graphical Layout" bar. I say [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) first. It's from Android Developer site, just incase, I'm putting another [tutorial link](http://apcmag.com/working-with-layouts-and-orientation-changes.htm) too.

Just to be clear, layout-port is for portait mode. If you want to design for lanscape, use layout-land. You can design for different screen size with this way too. Like [layout-sw600dp](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for those tutorials. Definitely going to check those out, it will be very useful for future projects :)

Answer (score 0):

The images dissapear because when the configuration changes, the layout gets redrawn.
You can set landscape mode by default on your app by adding this to OnCreate:

```
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or set it to portrait mode:

```
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        newConfig.orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: But I have to change the orientation in my app. This would solve the problem if I had to work with only one predetermined orientation.

Comment: Didn't work, but I somewhat solved the problem. Unless the GridView takes the whole screen, the images will disappear. After changing my Gridview to take the whole screen the images don't disappear, I still get that weird error though, but at least now I can display the images in both orientations.